# How to print two different type objects in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have Two object:

```
total_statuses = 10
status = {"A":2, "B":5, "C":3}
```

I want to print them in a simple table style without using any extra library such as tabulate.

```
Total    A   B    C
-------------------
 10      2   5    3

headers = ["Total"] + list(statuses.keys())
[print(f"{h:15}", end='') for h in header]
```

What is the effecient way to achieve this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is use a function:

```py
In [9]: def show(headers, statuses):
   ...:     [print(f"{h:15}", end='') for h in headers]
   ...:     print('\n' + '-' * (15 * len(statuses)+1))
   ...:     print(f'{str(sum(statuses.values())):15}', end='')
   ...:     for _, v in sorted(statuses.items()):
   ...:         print(f'{str(v):15}', end='')
   ...:     print()
   ...:
```

Output:

```
In [10]: show(headers, statuses)
Total          A              B              C
----------------------------------------------
10             2              5              3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
total_statuses = 10
status = {"A":2, "B":5, "C":3}

l1 = max(5, len(str(total_statuses))) + 4
l2 = len(str(status['A'])) + 3
l3 = len(str(status['B'])) + 3
l4 = len(str(status['C']))
lines = [
    'Total    '.ljust(l1) + 'A'.ljust(l2) + 'B'.ljust(l3) + 'C'.ljust(l4),
    '-' * (l1 + l2 + l3 + l4),
    str(total_statuses).ljust(l1) + str(status['A']).ljust(l2) + str(status['B']).ljust(l3) + str(status['C']).ljust(l4),
]
print(*lines, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
Total    A   B   C
------------------
10       2   5   3
```